# Letting 2 pointer pointing to same address

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have just started learning data structure and i was confused by pointer.

```
typedef struct{
    int* id;
}book;
```

I have created two book variables by `malloc()`

```
book* A;
A=(book*) malloc(sizeof(book)*2)
int bookid = 1234;
```

How can I make `A[0].id` and `A[1].id` pointing to book id to achieve that when I change one of it, another will change as well?

Comment: ***Why*** do you want a pointer to the id? That just makes no sense to me. Better make the `id` member a non-pointer.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think just for the sake of an example.

Comment: Messing up with pointers is really dangerous. Why shouldn't you use just "references" instead?

Comment: @Raindrop7 this isn't `c++` but `c`.

Answer (score 2):

You do

```
A[0].id = &bookid;
```

and

```
A[1].id = &bookid;
```

`&` sign gets the address of the variable.

Comment: There's a very big caveat that you really should mention here: The life-time of the variable `bookid`, and what could happen if it ends before the life-time of `A` ends.